# Overloading operators in C++ - compiles but crashes

Tags: c++, overloading, multiplication

I made a MegaInt class that could handle very large numbers and overloaded a few operators.  Unfortunately I've gotten stuck and my code just crashes.

Each MegaInt ojb has a vector value and an bool sign.  Each position of a number is placed in the vector (i.e. 4325 is vector value = {5,2,3,4}) and whether its sign (+ or -) is 1 or 0.

here's a bit of the code...

```
        #include <vector>
        #include <string>
        using namespace std;

        class MegaInt{
            friend class main;
            private:
                vector<int> value;
                bool sign; //true is pos, false is neg

            public:
                MegaInt(vector <int> x, bool y);
                MegaInt(string s);
                MegaInt(const MegaInt& m);
                MegaInt & operator*=(const MegaInt &rhs);

                #include <iostream>
                using namespace std;
                #include "MegaInt.h"
                #include <math.h>

                MegaInt::MegaInt(string s){
                    int pos = s.length()-1;

                    while (pos >= 0){
                        if(pos == 0 && s[pos] == '-'){
                            sign = false;
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (pos == 0 && s[pos] == '+'){
                            sign = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else{
                            sign = true;
                        }
                        if(s[pos] >= 48 && s[pos] <= 57)
                            value.push_back(s[pos]-48);
                        else{
                            value.clear();
                            break;
                        }
                        pos --;
                    }
                    chopoffleadingOs();
                }
                MegaInt::MegaInt(const MegaInt& m){
                    value = m.value;
                    sign = m.sign;
                }

                MegaInt operator*(const MegaInt& x, const MegaInt& y){
                    int multi = 0;
                    int temp;
                    vector<int> total;

                    for(int i = x.value.size()-1; i>=0; --i){
                        for(int j = y.value.size()-1, k = 0; j>=0; --j, ++k){
                            temp = x.value[i] * y.value[j];
                            if (total.size() <= (i + multi + 1))
                                                     total.resize(i + multi + 1 + 1);
                                                total[i + multi] += (temp % 10);
                                                temp = (temp - total[i]) / 10; 
                                                total[i + multi + 1] += temp;
                                                     }
                                                     multi++;
                                                    }

                                        reverse(total.begin(), total.end());

                return newTotal;
                }
```

I mainly seem to be stuck on the overloaded multiplication part.  The rest I think i got.

Thanks,
Noah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One likely the problem is here:

```
total[i+multi]+=(8%10);
```

You use the `total` vector, but haven't allocated memory for it. This can be done through the [`resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) function:

```
total.resize(MAX_SIZE);
```

A good way to find unexpected crashes is to use the debugger. If you run the program in a debugger, it will halt when there is a problem so you can examine variables and see both where the crash is and what may have caused it.

**Edit:**

If you don't know the size of the `total` vector beforehand, you have to resize it dynamically:

```
if (total.size() <= (i + multi + 1))
    total.resize(i + multi + 1 + 1);  // An extra +1 because vectors are zero-indexed

total[i+multi]+=(8%10);
// ...
```

Comment: i just changed the total[i+multi]+=(8%10); to total[i+multi]+=(temp%10);

Comment: @Noah_noobProgrammer99 I used the wrong function in my answer, it should be `resize` not `reserve`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: sorry I'm not sure how this will be able to help me.  I don't have a set limit to give to the vector.

Comment: I just tried that one and I still crash at that part of the code.. I get this error  No source available for "ntdll!LdrQueryProcessModuleInformation() at 0x772b15de"

Answer (score 0):

Always better to provide a fully compilable sample if possible; makes it easier for people to actually try a sample if they have time. Don't post everything - just the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Use the debugger - trace your code through the nested for loops and check what values you're getting for indexes into the vectors.

(As you're using Eclipse, double-click in the left margin to set a breakpoint on a line. Use  to run to a breakpoint. Highlight a variable or expression to watch and right-click the selection, then select 'Watch' from the menu to add it to the watch window.

Eclipse can be a little unhelpful where source code is concerned. If you're learning C++, I'd recommend something more friendlier - personally I would recommend Visual C++ Express (it's free). )

Comment: kk I put up the rest of the code.  I ran the debugger and got stuck around the mod part in the nest loop.  I'm still pretty new to c++ and am having trouble finding why this isn't working

Comment: lol oops I guess I misunderstood that part.. I've tried stepping through it but I'm still unsure of what the error is telling me.  Also how would I use the Watch window? Sorry I'm still new to this. I'm using eclips. And thanks for the help!

Comment: the error being :
No source available for "ntdll!LdrQueryProcessModuleInformation() at 0x772b15de"

Comment: LOL! wow that's not cool. Yea I've been on this issue for quite a while, its been keeping me from testing *= and ^ overloaded operators.  I guess I'll install NetBeans and see if that helps. Thanks again

Comment: Yea that helped, that 'watch' thing is great! It crashes right before the outer for loop's second loop. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can we edit some of the findings in this comment stream into the answer. It's being flagged as not an answer, and I can see why.